# Corte y pegue una carpeta de un proyecto a otro en una solución con capas visual studio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual

Corte carpetas con clases de una capa a otra y ahora la capa destino al referenciar una clase me pide referenciar la capa inicial donde corte la carpeta. ¿Como soluciono eso? Soy novato espero que me logren entender

Comment: Buenas para que te podamos ayudar, has de publicar el código para que podamos replicarlo, ver que falla, etc. Un enunciado de la forma que lo escribes da libertad a la interpretación de lo que has hecho.

Comment: Tienes que ver el namespace, que tiene este formato NombreDelProyecto.Carpeta1.Carpeta2 ...etc. Tu debes adecuarlo a la nueva estructura de tu proyecto